# Unserializing and Calling Data from Array in Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

Wordpress uses "_wp_attachment_metadata" to store information about videos that you upload to Wordpress.  Data such as the resolution, filesize, format, etc...  I'm trying to call that data, and display it.

The data is a serialized array:

```
a:13:{s:8:"lossless";b:0;s:7:"bitrate";i:6040338;s:12:"bitrate_mode";s:3:"cbr";s:8:"filesize";i:546209724;s:9:"mime_type";s:14:"video/x-ms-wmv";s:6:"length";i:695;s:16:"length_formatted";s:5:"11:34";s:5:"width";i:1280;s:6:"height";i:720;s:10:"fileformat";s:3:"asf";s:10:"dataformat";s:3:"wmv";s:7:"encoder";s:21:"Windows Media Video 9";s:5:"audio";a:12:{s:5:"codec";s:23:"Windows Media Audio 9.2";s:8:"channels";i:2;s:11:"sample_rate";i:44100;s:7:"bitrate";i:330258;s:15:"bits_per_sample";i:16;s:10:"dataformat";s:3:"wma";s:12:"bitrate_mode";s:3:"cbr";s:8:"lossless";b:0;s:7:"encoder";s:23:"Windows Media Audio 9.2";s:15:"encoder_options";s:41:"320 kbps, 44 kHz, stereo (A/V) 1-pass CBR";s:11:"channelmode";s:6:"stereo";s:17:"compression_ratio";d:0.2340263605442176875204296493393485434353351593017578125;}}
```

My code to pull in the data seems to work:

```
$woo_files_number = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'woo_files', true );
if( ! empty( $woo_files_number ) ) {
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom( $woo_files_number );
  $download_meta = $custom_fields['_wp_attachment_metadata'];
  }             
if( ! empty( $woo_files_number ) ) {
  echo $download_meta;
}
```

So now it displays the serialized data.  I'm very confused on how to *unserialize* the data, and then display attributes from it.  When I run it through an online unserializer, it shows me the data contained in the serialized array is:

```
Array
(
[lossless] => 
[bitrate] => 6040338
[bitrate_mode] => cbr
[filesize] => 546209724
[mime_type] => video/x-ms-wmv
[length] => 695
[length_formatted] => 11:34
[width] => 1280
[height] => 720
[fileformat] => asf
[dataformat] => wmv
[encoder] => Windows Media Video 9
[audio] => Array
(
[codec] => Windows Media Audio 9.2
[channels] => 2
[sample_rate] => 44100
[bitrate] => 330258
[bits_per_sample] => 16
[dataformat] => wma
[bitrate_mode] => cbr
[lossless] => 
[encoder] => Windows Media Audio 9.2
[encoder_options] => 320 kbps, 44 kHz, stereo (A/V) 1-pass CBR
[channelmode] => stereo
[compression_ratio] => 0.234026360544
)
```

**So my question, is how do I finish up that bit of code, to unserialize the data and then be able to output parts of it such as length_formatted, width, height, etc......**

I've been searching around here for a few days trying to hack and understand it but I'm at my wits end and cant quite seem to figure out the finishing piece.  Thanks so much for your help and time!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just query the post meta directly instead of pulling it from get_post_custom.

If you're not using any of the other custom fields you're loading data you aren't using.

Instead of your code:

```
  if( ! empty( $woo_files_number ) ) {
     $custom_fields = get_post_custom( $woo_files_number );
     $download_meta = $custom_fields['_wp_attachment_metadata'];
  }
```

Just get the post meta directly.

```
if( ! empty( $woo_files_number ) ) {
  $download_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_attachment_metadata', true);
  // Print out the array in a nice format for easy reading. 
  echo '<pre>'; 
  print_r($download_meta);
  echo '</pre>; 
}
```

Also post this on the wordpress stack website next time and you'll get a lot more hits.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm now able to pull data from that array and format it.  Much appreciated.